# Convert a string to an integer produced unexpected result

Tags: c++

I am a new learner to c++, and right now going through the "Convert a string a an integer" problem. Following is my code, but when I tried it on Xcode, it printed 1068, which was not my expectation. I tried some others, the same bug just appeared. Anyone could help me about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int myAtoi(const char* str) {
    int Res=0;
    bool Sign=true;
    while(*str==' '){str++;}

    if(!isdigit(*str)&&*str!='+'&&*str!='-')
              {return 0;}
    if(*str=='+'||*str=='-'){
        if(!isdigit(*(str+1))){return 0;}
         else if (*str=='-'){Sign=false;}
          str++;
    }

    while (isdigit(*str)){
        if(Res>INT_MAX){return Sign?INT_MAX:INT_MIN;}
        Res=Res*10+int(*str+'0');
        str++;
    }
    return Sign?Res:-Res;


}


int main(){
    int sample=myAtoi("  +12");
    cout<<sample<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if(Res>INT_MAX)` how do you expect this to happen?

Comment: Yes you are right! I should have exchanged the position of this if condition and "Res=Res*10+int(*str-'0');

Comment: So if you exchange those expressions you expect that variable of type `int` can become bigger than `INT_MAX`? Do you know what `INT_MAX` stands for?

Comment: It's probably more effective to subtract `'0'` from `*str` than to add it.  You'll still need to deal with the overflow before it happens, as others have indicated.

Answer (score 3):

You should be doing `Res=Res*10+int(*str-'0');` instead of what you've done. `*str` is the character you're currently looking at. And to convert it into integer equivalent, you have to subtract the ASCII value of `'0'`.

It is quite intuitive that ASCII value of a digit `n` would be `n + ASCII(0)`

Comment: Re: "It is quite intuitive" - even better, the C and C++ language definitions **require** that the character set have its digits contiguous and increasing. There's no need to assume that the encoding is ASCII.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!